# I can't make changes to a specific Instance of a recurring event in Google Calendar

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, google-calendar-api, google-sheets-api

I am utilizing an Apps Script code to synchronize Google Calendar and Google Sheets. This allows me to generate calendar events from Google Sheets and vice versa, resulting in the information being populated in the Google Sheet. However, I have encountered an issue with recurring events.

Whenever I modify one occurrence of a recurring event in the calendar, it affects all the other instances in the Google Sheet. Alternatively, sometimes the changes do not propagate at all. For instance, if I delete one instance from the calendar application, it does not get removed from the sheets. Instead, a new event is created with a different date.

My objective is to be able to make changes to a specific occurrence of a recurring event and have those changes only affect that particular instance, without impacting the rest.

Any help rendered to me will be highly appreciated.

I tried to modify the code to handle recurring events separately but it has not worked either.

This is the code I am using :

```
//Sheet -Calendar Sync - original code

//This code is meant to automate creation of Google calendar events 

// the function "onOpen()" Runs when the spreadsheet is opened and adds the menu options to the spreadsheet menu

const onOpen = () => {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
    .createMenu('myTime')
    .addItem('Sync calendar events', 'run')
    .addItem('Settings', 'settings')
    .addItem('Updt Deleted Events', 'checkDeletedEvents')
    .addToUi();
};

/**
 * Opens the sidebar
 */
const settings = () => {
  const html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Page')
    .setTitle('Settings');

  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(html);
};

/**
* returns the settings from the script properties
*/
const getSettings = () => {
  const settings = {};
  
  // get the current settings
  const savedCalendarSettings = JSON.parse(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('calendar') || '[]');
  
  // get the primary calendar
  const primaryCalendar = CalendarApp.getAllCalendars()
    .filter((cal) => cal.isMyPrimaryCalendar())
    .map((cal) => ({
      name: 'Primary calendar',
      id: cal.getId()
    }));
    
  // get the secondary calendars
  const secundaryCalendars = CalendarApp.getAllCalendars()
    .filter((cal) => cal.isOwnedByMe() && !cal.isMyPrimaryCalendar())
    .map((cal) => ({
      name: cal.getName(),
      id: cal.getId()
    }));

  // the current available calendars
  const availableCalendars = primaryCalendar.concat(secundaryCalendars);
  
  // find any calendars that were removed
  const unavailebleCalendars = [];
  savedCalendarSettings.forEach((savedCalendarSetting) => {
    if (!availableCalendars.find((availableCalendar) => availableCalendar.id === savedCalendarSetting.id)) {
      unavailebleCalendars.push(savedCalendarSetting);
    }
  });
 
  // map the current settings to the available calendars
  const calendarSettings = availableCalendars.map((availableCalendar) => {
    if (savedCalendarSettings.find((savedCalendar) => savedCalendar.id === availableCalendar.id)) {
      availableCalendar.sync = true;

    }
    return availableCalendar;
  });

  // add the calendar settings to the settings
  settings.calendarSettings = calendarSettings;

  const savedFrom = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('syncFrom');
  settings.syncFrom = savedFrom;
 
  const savedTo = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('syncTo');
  settings.syncTo = savedTo;

  const savedIsUpdateTitle = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('isUpdateTitle') === 'true';
  settings.isUpdateCalendarItemTitle = savedIsUpdateTitle;

  const savedIsUseCategoriesAsCalendarItemTitle = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('isUseCategoriesAsCalendarItemTitle') === 'true';
  settings.isUseCategoriesAsCalendarItemTitle = savedIsUseCategoriesAsCalendarItemTitle;

  const savedIsUpdateDescription = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('isUpdateDescription') === 'true';
  settings.isUpdateCalendarItemDescription = savedIsUpdateDescription;
  
  return settings;
};

/**
* Saves the settings from the sidebar
*/
const saveSettings = (settings) => {
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('calendar', JSON.stringify(settings.calendarSettings));
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('syncFrom', settings.syncFrom);
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('syncTo', settings.syncTo);
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('isUpdateTitle', settings.isUpdateCalendarItemTitle);
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('isUseCategoriesAsCalendarItemTitle', settings.isUseCategoriesAsCalendarItemTitle);
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('isUpdateDescription', settings.isUpdateCalendarItemDescription);
  return 'Settings saved';
};

/**
 * Builds the myTime object and runs the synchronisation
 */
const run = () => {
  'use strict';
  myTime({
    mainSpreadsheetId: SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId(),
  }).run();
};

/**
 * The main function used for the synchronisation
 * @param {Object} par The main parameter object.
 * @return {Object} The myTime Object.
 */
const myTime = (par) => {
  'use strict';

  /**
  * Format the sheet
  */
  const formatSheet = () => {
    // sort decending on start date 
    hourSheet.sort(3, false);

    // hide the technical columns
    hourSheet.hideColumns(1, 2);

    // remove any extra rows
    if (hourSheet.getLastRow() > 1 && hourSheet.getLastRow() < hourSheet.getMaxRows()) {
      hourSheet.deleteRows(hourSheet.getLastRow() + 1, hourSheet.getMaxRows() - hourSheet.getLastRow());
    }

    // set the validation for the customers
    let rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation()
      .requireValueInRange(categoriesSheet.getRange('A2:A'), true)
      .setAllowInvalid(true)
      .build();
    hourSheet.getRange('I2:I').setDataValidation(rule);

    // set the validation for the projects
    rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation()
      .requireValueInRange(categoriesSheet.getRange('B2:B'), true)
      .setAllowInvalid(true)
      .build();
    hourSheet.getRange('J2:J').setDataValidation(rule);

    // set the validation for the tsaks
    rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation()
      .requireValueInRange(categoriesSheet.getRange('C2:C'), true)
      .setAllowInvalid(true)
      .build();
    hourSheet.getRange('K2:K').setDataValidation(rule);

    if(isUseCategoriesAsCalendarItemTitle) {
      hourSheet.getRange('L2:L').setFormulaR1C1('IF(OR(R[0]C[-3]="tbd";R[0]C[-2]="tbd";R[0]C[-1]="tbd");""; CONCATENATE(R[0]C[-3];"|";R[0]C[-2];"|";R[0]C[-1];"|"))');
    }
    // set the hours, month, week and number columns
    hourSheet.getRange('P2:P').setFormulaR1C1('=IF(R[0]C[-12]="";"";R[0]C[-12]-R[0]C[-13])');
    hourSheet.getRange('Q2:Q').setFormulaR1C1('=IF(R[0]C[-13]="";"";month(R[0]C[-13]))');
    hourSheet.getRange('R2:R').setFormulaR1C1('=IF(R[0]C[-14]="";"";WEEKNUM(R[0]C[-14];2))');
    hourSheet.getRange('S2:S').setFormulaR1C1('=R[0]C[-3]');
  };

  /**
     * Activate the synchronisation
     */
  function run() {
    console.log('Started processing hours.');

    const processCalendar = (setting) => {
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();

      // current calendar info
      const calendarName = setting.name;
      const calendarId = setting.id;

      console.log(`processing ${calendarName} with the id ${calendarId} from ${syncStartDate} to ${syncEndDate}`);

      // get the calendar
      const calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);

      // get the calendar events and create lookups
      const events = calendar.getEvents(syncStartDate, syncEndDate);
      const eventsLookup = events.reduce((jsn, event) => {
        jsn[event.getId()] = event;
        return jsn;
      }, {});

      // get the sheet events and create lookups
      const existingEvents = hourSheet.getDataRange().getValues().slice(1);
      const existingEventsLookUp = existingEvents.reduce((jsn, row, index) => {
        if (row[0] !== calendarId) {
          return jsn;
        }
        jsn[row[1]] = {
          event: row,
          row: index + 2
        };
        return jsn;
      }, {});

    
      // handle a calendar event
      const handleEvent = (event) => {
        const eventId = event.getId();

        // new event
        if (!existingEventsLookUp[eventId]) {
          hourSheet.appendRow([
            calendarId,
            eventId,
            event.getStartTime(),
            event.getEndTime(),
            calendarName,
            event.getCreators().join(','),
            event.getTitle(),
            event.getDescription(),
            event.getTag('Client') || 'tbd',
            event.getTag('Project') || 'tbd',
            event.getTag('Task') || 'tbd',
            (isUpdateCalendarItemTitle) ? '' : event.getTitle(),
            (isUpdateCalendarItemDescription) ? '' : event.getDescription(),
            event.getGuestList().map((guest) => guest.getEmail()).join(','),
            event.getLocation(),
            undefined,
            undefined,
            undefined,
            undefined
          ]);
          return true;
        }
          
         // existing event
        const exisitingEvent = existingEventsLookUp[eventId].event;
        const exisitingEventRow = existingEventsLookUp[eventId].row;

        if (event.getStartTime() - exisitingEvent[startTimeColumn - 1] !== 0) {
          hourSheet.getRange(exisitingEventRow, startTimeColumn).setValue(event.getStartTime());
        }

        if (event.getEndTime() - exisitingEvent[endTimeColumn - 1] !== 0) {
          hourSheet.getRange(exisitingEventRow, endTimeColumn).setValue(event.getEndTime());
        }

        if (event.getCreators().join(',') !== exisitingEvent[creatorsColumn - 1]) {
          hourSheet.getRange(exisitingEventRow, creatorsColumn).setValue(event.getCreators()[0]);
        }

        if (event.getGuestList().map((guest) => guest.getEmail()).join(',') !== exisitingEvent[guestListColumn - 1]) {
          hourSheet.getRange(exisitingEventRow, guestListColumn).setValue(event.getGuestList().map((guest) => guest.getEmail()).join(','));
        }

        if (event.getLocation() !== exisitingEvent[locationColumn - 1]) {
          hourSheet.getRange(exisitingEventRow, locationColumn).setValue(event.getLocation());
        }

        if(event.getTitle() !== exisitingEvent[titleColumn - 1]) {
          if(!isUpdateCalendarItemTitle) {
            hourSheet.getRange(exisitingEventRow, titleColumn).setValue(event.getTitle());
          }
          if(isUpdateCalendarItemTitle) {
            event.setTitle(exisitingEvent[titleColumn - 1]);
          }
        }
       
        if(event.getDescription() !== exisitingEvent[descriptionColumn - 1]) { 
          if(!isUpdateCalendarItemDescription) {
            hourSheet.getRange(exisitingEventRow, descriptionColumn).setValue(event.getDescription());
          }
          if(isUpdateCalendarItemDescription) {
            event.setDescription(exisitingEvent[descriptionColumn - 1]);
          }
        }

        return true;
      };

      // process each event for the calendar
      events.every(handleEvent);

      // remove any events in the sheet that are not in de calendar
      existingEvents.every((event, index) => {
        if (event[0] !== calendarId) {
          return true;
        };

        if (eventsLookup[event[1]]) {
          return true;
        }
        
        if (event[3] < syncStartDate) {
          return true;
        }

        hourSheet.getRange(index + 2, 1, 1, 20).clear();
        return true;
      });

      return true;
    };

    // process the calendars
    settings.calendarSettings.filter((calenderSetting) => calenderSetting.sync === true).every(processCalendar);

    formatSheet();
    SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(hourSheet);

    console.log('Finished processing hours.');
  }

  const mainSpreadSheetId = par.mainSpreadsheetId;
  const mainSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(mainSpreadSheetId);
  const hourSheet = mainSpreadsheet.getSheetByName('Hours');
  const categoriesSheet = mainSpreadsheet.getSheetByName('Categories');
  const settings = getSettings();

  const syncStartDate = new Date();
  syncStartDate.setDate(syncStartDate.getDate() - Number(settings.syncFrom));
  
  const syncEndDate = new Date();
  syncEndDate.setDate(syncEndDate.getDate() + Number(settings.syncTo));
  
  const isUpdateCalendarItemTitle = settings.isUpdateCalendarItemTitle;
  const isUseCategoriesAsCalendarItemTitle = settings.isUseCategoriesAsCalendarItemTitle;
  const isUpdateCalendarItemDescription = settings.isUpdateCalendarItemDescription;

  const startTimeColumn = 3;
  const endTimeColumn = 4;
  const creatorsColumn = 6;
  const originalTitleColumn = 7;
  const originalDescriptionColumn = 8;
  const clientColumn = 9;
  const projectColumn = 10;
  const taskColumn = 11;
  const titleColumn = 12;
  const descriptionColumn = 13;
  const guestListColumn = 14;
  const locationColumn = 15;

  return Object.freeze({
    run: run,
  });
};


 function checkDeletedEvents() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Hours");
  var calendarId = "ac766277aaa7a2ca8135315e665a10687b02a9c0aeb1f314d55a249c015bb153@group.calendar.google.com";
  var now = new Date();
  var events = Calendar.Events.list(calendarId, {timeMin: now.toISOString(), singleEvents: true}).items;
  var eventIds = events.map(function(event) { return event.id; });
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var values = range.getValues();
  for (var i = values.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    var row = values[i];
    if (row[0] && eventIds.indexOf(row[0]) === -1) {
      sheet.deleteRow(i + 1);
    }
  }
 //run();
 checkUpdatedEvents(sheet, existingEventsLookUp, calendarId);
}

function checkUpdatedEvents(sheet, existingEventsLookUp, calendarId) {
  for (var eventId in existingEventsLookUp) {
    if (!existingEventsLookUp.hasOwnProperty(eventId)) {
      continue;
    }
    var eventInfo = existingEventsLookUp[eventId];
    var eventExists = CalendarApp.getEventById(eventId);
    if (eventExists) {
      var event = eventExists.getOriginalCalendarEvent();
      var eventRow = sheet.getRange(eventInfo.row, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
      if (event.getStartTime().getTime() !== eventRow[2].getTime() || event.getEndTime().getTime() !== eventRow[3].getTime()) {
        sheet.getRange(eventInfo.row, 3).setValue(event.getStartTime());
        sheet.getRange(eventInfo.row, 4).setValue(event.getEndTime());
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `This allows me to generate calendar events from Google Sheets and vice versa, resulting in the information being populated in the Google Sheet` It's not clear what triggers an update of a specific occurrence of a recurring event. Would you please supply an example of your spreadsheet data (as text).

Answer (score 0):

Simple. First get the instance id of the recurring event, then use that instance id when calling `Calendar.events.update`.

```
updatedEvent = Calendar.Events.update(event, calID, instanceId, { sendUpdates: 'all' });
```

Where:

- `event` - the request body
- `calID` - calendar ID
- `instanceId` - recurring event instance id.

Comment: Hello Jeremy ,sorry i have not been in action for while that why it took me long to reply . I  really appreciate your assistance , thank  you.

Comment: I happened to use your  idea and decided to implement it by creating a separate function to achieve my objective. Regrettably, the function didn't work as intended. Below is the code for the function. I would appreciate your advice on this matter.                        "

Comment: the code is at link :https://docs.google.com/document/d/1OulTnoEY0d0HgjGjbuUmebDMvAKjllsTd2x77AHJp6w/edit